# Is it good practice to replace negative predictions with zero?

Tags: predictive-models

Given a model that predicts the value of a non negative variable is it okay to replace the negative predictions with zero? Is there a different methodology of dealing with this problem? Are the any complications?

Comment: Related and possibly enlightening: [Can a mathematically sound prediction interval have a negative lower bound?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/92443/1352) and [Is it bad to have error bars constructed with standard deviation that spans to the negative scale while the variable itself shouldn't be negative?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478605/1352)

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to use a model that respects the non-negativity of your outcome variable.

For example, if you are modeling probabilities, use logistic regression, not a linear regression with the probability as the outcome. If you are modeling counts, use a Poisson or negative binomial regression. If your values are all strictly positive, try modeling the logarithm of the values or using a generalized linear model with a logarithmic link.